# Django migrate command fails with foreign key to user model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a very simple test application, test_app, in django 1.7b2 that consists of only one model:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class TestModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations test_app`, I get no errors and the migration file is created successfully.  However, when I come to run `python manage.py migrate`, I get the following error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
  Apply all migrations: test_app, auth
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying test_app.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
427, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 337,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py
", line 145, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 60
, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 88
, in apply_migration
    if self.detect_soft_applied(migration):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 13
2, in detect_soft_applied
    apps = project_state.render()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 63, i
n render
    model=dangling_lookup[0]))
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field auth.Permission.content_
type: contenttypes.ContentType
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `contenttypes` listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`? Have you run `syncdb`?

Comment: Yes `contenttypes` is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`.  I have not run `syncdb` since that is depreciated in 1.7 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations), however I have run `migrate` which is what replaces `syncdb`

Comment: Oops, sorry, haven't noticed your 1.7 note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a known bug and is being tracked in django ticket [#22485](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22485)